# CSS fontface fallbackfont

Tags: css

When i use fontface, the browser needs some time before the font is downloaded and rendered, until then the browser default font is shown. I have tried to give Arial as fallbackfont and as general HTML/BODY font, but this does not change the problem.

is there a way to avoid this?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'StrukturProBold';
src: url('fonts/strukturpro_bold_ubasic/StrukturPro-Bold-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/strukturpro_bold_ubasic/StrukturPro-Bold-webfont.eot?iefix') format('eot'),
     url('fonts/strukturpro_bold_ubasic/StrukturPro-Bold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/strukturpro_bold_ubasic/StrukturPro-Bold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/strukturpro_bold_ubasic/StrukturPro-Bold-webfont.svg#webfontpQgNQDw9') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
body, html {
 font-family: "StrukturProBold", Arial, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif, "open-serif", open-serif;
}
h1 {
 font-family: "StrukturProBold", Arial, Helvetica, FreeSans, sans-serif, "open-serif", open-serif;
}
```

Comment: the default font is going to be shown until a suitable replacement is downloaded. What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is, that the default browser font looks very different then the loadet font. So it looks kind of bad for +/- 1 second. I would like the Fallbackfont to be used until then, not the browser default font.

Comment: I believe that on windows Arial *is* the browser's default sans-serif font. and that Times New Roman is the default serif font. Helvetica and Times are the defaults on Mac (if I remember correctly, please correct me if I'm mistaken). You'll just have to use a more appropriate fallback that browsers are likely to have (Georgia, Verdana, Times, Arial, Helvetica, etc)

Comment: You are not mistaken. I tested it on mac. In safari and chrome its instant, you don't have time to see any effect. But in FireFox georgia or something like this, is used until the font is loaded. My fallback font declaration is allready complete, i just used Arial for the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless the visitor has the specialty font installed on their system, the browser has to download it just like it would an image file, or a linked stylesheet or .js file.

From reading the comments above, you're probably already doing the best that you can.
StrukturProBold is just a simple sans-serif font.

You can expand your list of secondary font choices though, maybe Arial and Helvetica aren't as good of a choice as say Verdana, or Trebuchet

```
font-family: "StrukturProBold", Trebuchet, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

Comment: my font declaration already looks like this. I just used only arial for this example. I have correted my example so you can see how it realy looks like

Comment: sorry you where right, when i copy pasted my example i saw that i had an encoding error after the first font declaration (some wired character), so the rest was not interpreted by the browser right. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

This is called a "Flash Of Un-styled Text" (or FOUT). You wont see it in Webkit browsers, because they hide the text until the font has been loaded. If you want to be more agressive with forcing other browsers to hide the FOUT, you can do it with some pre-written JavaScript.

Paul Irish explains it all here:

http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/

Here's the code you need:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js"></script>
<script>
WebFont.load({
  custom: {
    families: ['yourfont'],
    urls : ['http://example.com/yourfontdeclaration.css']
  }
});
</script>
```

and some CSS:

```
h2 {
  font-family: 'yourfont', helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.wf-loading h2 { 
  visibility: hidden; 
}
```

Comment: oh so sad you where to late, i would give you the right answer!

Comment: You can [change the accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/is-it-possible-to-change-the-chosen-answer), if you wish ;)